# How to fill missing values with similar rows median

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I fill missing values with similar rows `median` for titanic dataset?

I have a `Age` column where I have 80 missing values and I want to fill those missing values by taking the median of similar rows of there other columns. `['SibSp', 'Parch', 'Pclass']`

Assume this eg:

```
    Age SibSp Parch Pclass
0   28   2      1     2
1  NaN   2      1     2
2   30   3      3     1
3   40   4      3     3
4   30   2      1     2
5   40   2      1     2
```

Now I want to fill the `NaN` in `Age` column by considering similar value in other three columns. In this case I have three rows with sample values as row 1.

```
   Age SibSp Parch Pclass
0   28   2      1     2
4   30   2      1     2
5   40   2      1     2
```

The median here for `Age` col is 30. So fill the NaN with 30.

*Required output*.

```
    Age SibSp Parch Pclass
0   28   2      1     2
1   30   2      1     2  # Fill with median of those above three rows.
2   30   3      3     1
3   40   4      3     3
4   30   2      1     2
5   40   2      1     2
```

This is something I wrote but it's not working.

```
# Filling missing values Of Age.
for i in combined.Age[combined.Age.isna()].index.tolist():
    age_med = combined.Age.median()
    mask1 = combined.SibSp.eq(combined.iloc[i].SibSp)
    mask2 = combined.Parch.eq(combined.iloc[i].Parch)
    mask3 = combined.Pclass.eq(combined.iloc[i].Pclass)
    age_pred = combined.Age[mask1 & mask2 & mask3].median()
    combined.iloc[i]['Age'] = age_pred
```

I'm sure there are better ways to do it using `groupby` or something but I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for return `median` with same size `Series` like original `DataFrame`, so is possible use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
med = df.groupby(['SibSp', 'Parch', 'Pclass'])['Age'].transform('median')
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(med)
```

Or similar solution with lambda function:

```
df['Age'] = (df.groupby(['SibSp', 'Parch', 'Pclass'])['Age']
               .transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median())))

print (df)
    Age  SibSp  Parch  Pclass
0  28.0      2      1       2
1  30.0      2      1       2
2  30.0      3      3       1
3  40.0      4      3       3
4  30.0      2      1       2
5  40.0      2      1       2
```

Comment: Jezrael, Are there any performance benefits with using `fillna` on large datasets or I can also use lambda function?

Comment: @Rakesh - Performance is different, I guess if large data first solution should be faster.